# Adding custom methods to standard ruby objects

Tags: ruby

How can I add custom methods to standard ruby objects, such as strings and integers?

I have seen this in, for example, rails, and the mojinizer library for ruby that can convert a romaji string into hiragana, as in

```
"tsukue".hiragana #=> "つくえ"
```

Comment: You can simply reopen class (in this case it would be `String` class) and define the method you need. But it isn't advisable, especially for Ruby beginners.

Comment: @MarekLipka prepending a module is a preferable way since it allows to call `super` on while overwriting methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open the class and add the method.  You can open a class as many times as you need to.

```
class Fixnum
  def lucky?
    self == 7
  end
end

95.lucky?
=> false

7.lucky?
=> true
```

It's a useful ability and we've all done it.  Take care that your code is maintainable and that you don't break basic functionality.

Answer (score 6):

If you indeed feel a necessity to extend default behavior of classes you do not own (which is basically a very bad idea, one should use other ways to achieve this functionality,) you should *not* re-open classes, but [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) a module with the requested functionality instead:

```
String.prepend(Module.new do
  def uppercase!
    self.replace upcase
  end
end)

str = "hello"
str.uppercase!
#⇒ "HELLO"
str
#⇒ "HELLO"
```

If the method to be overwritten existed in the class, it might still be accessed with a call to `super` from inside the module method.

Comment: You could also wrap the `prepend` into a Refinement for isolation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I consider `refinement`s an absolute evil and never use them, because the cat that barks here and moos there is much worse contract than the cat that meows everywhere. Refinements-related issues are incredibly hard to diagnose, locate and debug. Whether I do not need the cat to bark somewhere, I’d better implement a proxy and delegate.

Answer (score 1):

```
class String
  def add_exclamation_mark
    self + "!"
  end
end

> "hello".add_exclamation_mark
"hello!"
```

That way you are adding new methods to a String class.

Comment: This answer brings no additional value to the previously given answer by @SteveTurczyn plus the name of the method is confusing since it does not indeed add the exclamation mark to the receiver, it just returns a receiver appended with an exclamation mark.